# How to get SLC.pdb to analyze memory dump

Tags: windbg, symbols, crash-dumps, debug-symbols

I am using windbg 6.12.0002.633 X86 on Windows Vista to analyze memory dumps for memory leaks.
I'm trying to use the command ``dumpheap -stat`to determine the quantities of objects in the heap.
Unfortunately, I'm getting the error`*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for SLC.dll`. I have activated`!sym noisy`to show where the error comes from and the file SLC.pdb is just not available on the symbol server.
I have googled the file but haven't found such a downloadable file.
The last line in the log output says:`Couldn't resolve error at "mpheap -stat"`.
I can't proceed debugging because I'm getting this error permanently.

Does anyone know where I can get a SLC.pdb file or another way to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error messages seems a little incomplete. The `!dumpheap` command is part of the SOS extension used to debug managed .NET code under WinDbg. Is that what you're trying to do? You should be able to use the command even without correct PDB files for all modules.

How did you load SOS? Can you use any other SOS commands?

Comment: You are right. The command was the wrong one! `heap -s` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Writing

```
 dumpheap -stat
```

Will result in

```
Couldn't resolve error at 'mpheap -stat'
```

However, this will work:

```
!dumpheap -stat
```

Note the exclamation mark !